# Header - Footer Include in another Html file

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a website and I would like to be able to add external html files to another html file. I have three files. One is Header.html, the other one is the index.html, and the other one is the footer.html. What I would like is to add header and footer inside each of the new pages that I create for my website so I can update header or footer and be updated to all the pages that are included. I know, and I have done this before using server side programming language like PHP, and I have used w3schools method. Both are working, but I would like to find new ways of implement html to another html document but to **be supported**. I would like **plain JS** way, or **html way**. **No jQuery**. Hopefully someone guru out there can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: this is too broad as asked.  There are an entire class of frameworks that have been written to handle this kind of page manipulation, called Single Page Applications (SPAs).  You might just use one of the many popular ones, or take some of the techniques that they employ, but it's quite a bit more challenging than just putting a couple lines of JS on the page.

Comment: Thank you @claies for your answer. I am looking for a solution without any frameworks. I can use server side programming language to achieve what I want but I would like to know if there is an html or plain JavaScript way to do that. I would like to implement my header.html and footer.html to all my pages.html and when I make an update to either header.html or footer.html to be updates in all of my pages that they include header and footer.

Comment: well you may not want to use a framework, but you should consider copying what one of the popular frameworks do, at least.  They take into consideration many possible scenarios that you may not even know to consider.  any answer that would even scratch the surface of how to do this would be too long for this format.

Comment: for example: typically, this is an AJAX `XMLHttpRequest` to get the extra files, read them, and then replace the sections of the DOM where the files go with their contents.  If not done right, this can cause your users to see blank areas or placeholder text during this loading period.  Most SPA frameworks have some way to control this "blinking" or "placeholding".

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a very maintainable method for a large or complex site, fetch a markup file using ajax and append header/fooder containers to the top and bottom of the body on page load.

Sorry in advance that this answer is using jQuery, although you can do all of these steps in vanilla.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/path/to/markup",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(html) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('body').prepend($(html).find('#header'));
            $('body').append($(html).find('#footer'));
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this method, this worked fine for me.

your html code..

```
<div id="header"></div>

<!--your body -->

<div id="footer"></div>
```

your javascript code

```
function include_header() {
document.getElementById("header").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="header.html" ></object>';
}
function include_footer() {
document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="footer.html" ></object>';
}
```

> call these function after DOM loaded. something like this.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("call your functions here");
      include_header();
     include_footer();
  });
```